# Proving that the unit cube cannot be tripled (with straight edge and compass)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> I would like to show the unit cube cannot be tripled using a straightedge and compass.

I note that the side of a cube that has been tripled would have a side length of $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{3}$

But then the minimal polynomial for this $\alpha$ is $f(x)=x^3-3$

Then $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=3\neq 2^{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and hence our choice of $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{3}$ cannot be constructible and hence we cannot triple the cube.

This is relevant because I know that $\alpha$ is constructible only if $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=2^n$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$

I was wondering if this approach to the proof was okay, or would anyone recommend proving it differently/better or correctly (if this approach is incorrect)?

Comment: Your proof is good, but I think there are elements with power-of-two degree which are not constructible.  $\alpha$ is constructible iff it is in a radical tower over $\mathbb{Q}$, which implies $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^n$, but the reverse implication needn't hold.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. I wasn't sure if this was the correct mode of attack for this problem since wouldn't this means regardless if I was tripling it or quadrupling it, etc, then dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ would always be $3$ and hence the unit cube would never be able to tripled, quadrupled, etc...?

Comment: No I think your solution is fine. I think it does follow in a similar way that the cube cannot be quadrupled.  But, for example, this method would not work to show that the cube cannot be duplicated 27-fold, since $\sqrt[3]{27}$ is not degree three.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see what you mean. Well, you've answered my question, so if you want to change the comment to an answer I'll be happy to choose you as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is fine. It does follow in a similar way that the cube cannot be quadrupled.  But, for example, this method would not work to show that the cube cannot be duplicated 8-fold, since $\sqrt[3]{8}$ is not degree three.